# ADBannerView appering in landscape mode, but not in thr portrait mode

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.2

How to autochange the size of ADBannerView when iphone is in landscape mode or portrait mode.

iAd appears in landscape mode but not in the portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

you must use CGRectMake method.

code ex :

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientation Portrait) {

banner.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,768,70)

}

else {

banner.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,1024,70)

}
```